# Rescaling input to CNNs

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning

What is the general consensus on rescaling images that have different sizes? I have read that one approach is to rescale the largest size of an image to a fixed size. It's not clear to me how only rescaling one of the dimensions would lead to uniform image shapes across the dataset.

Are there other approaches, e.g. would it work to take the average size of the two dimensions and then rescale the dimensions of each image to the mean of each dimension across the dataset?

Is it important which interpolation method is used in the rescaling?

Would it make sense to simply take an nxm part of each image and cut off the rest of each image?

Is there a list of approaches people have used and how they perform in different scenarios.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to achieve specifically and what you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the target application of the CNNs. For object detection/classification usually a sliding window approach or cropping is used. For the first option, sliding window is moved around the image and for every patch (with different overlapping criterion) a prediction is made. This predictions are then filtered with other pooling or filter strategies.

For image segmentation (aka semantic segmentation), similar approaches are used. 1) image scaling + segmenting + scaling back to its original size. 2) different image patches + segmentation of each, or 3) sliding window segmentation + maxpooling. With the option (3) each pixel has a N = HxW votes (where N is the size of the sliding window). This N predictions are then aggregated into a maxixmum-voting classifier (similar to ensemble models on Random Forest and other classifiers).

So, in short, I believe there is no short nor unique answer to this question. The decision you take will depend in the goal you try to achieve with the CNN, and of course, the quality of your approach will have an impact in the performance of the CNN. I don't know about any study of this kind though.